# AS3 XML delete node

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have this XML structure:

```
<dbase>
   <employee>
      <Name>NAME</Name>
      <Surname>SURNAME</Surname>
      <Company>COMPANY</Company>
      <Date>DATE</Date>
      <Compare>1377390433625</Compare>
   </employee>
</dbase>
```

I'd like to know how to search for the Compare value an delete the employee if there is a match.

I'll appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the following code will be useful. Assuming that the xml structure will be like this:

```
        <dbase>
        <employee>
            <Name>NAME</Name>
            <Surname>SURNAME</Surname>
            <Company>COMPANY</Company>
            <Date>DATE</Date>
            <Compare>1377390433625</Compare>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <Name>WILL BE DELETED</Name>
            <Surname>SURNAME</Surname>
            <Company>COMPANY</Company>
            <Date>DATE</Date>
            <Compare>1234</Compare>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <Name>NAME</Name>
            <Surname>SURNAME</Surname>
            <Company>COMPANY</Company>
            <Date>DATE</Date>
            <Compare>34878937</Compare>
        </employee>         
    </dbase>
```

In the next code, i will delete the node with `Compare = 1234`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public function init():void{
                delete myXML.employee.(elements('Compare') == '1234')[0];
                txt.text = myXML.toString();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:XML id="myXML">
        <dbase>
            <employee>
                <Name>NAME</Name>
                <Surname>SURNAME</Surname>
                <Company>COMPANY</Company>
                <Date>DATE</Date>
                <Compare>1377390433625</Compare>
            </employee>
            <employee>
                <Name>WILL BE DELETED</Name>
                <Surname>SURNAME</Surname>
                <Company>COMPANY</Company>
                <Date>DATE</Date>
                <Compare>1234</Compare>
            </employee>
            <employee>
                <Name>NAME</Name>
                <Surname>SURNAME</Surname>
                <Company>COMPANY</Company>
                <Date>DATE</Date>
                <Compare>34878937</Compare>
            </employee>         
        </dbase>
    </mx:XML>
    <mx:TextArea id="txt" width="400" height="400" />
</mx:Application>
```

Basically this line delete the node that matches with the number as i want (in this case, **1234**):

```
delete myXML.employee.(elements('Compare') == '1234')[0];
```

You can try this here **[LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108036807/ExReadXml_02.swf)**.
I hope this will be useful.

**(Edited) 2013-08-26**:
Here the **[LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108036807/ExampleXmlProject.fxp)** for download the project. This file is a .fxp file, you can import this, click in **File** --> **Import...** --> **Flash Builder Project..** --> **select the .fxp file**.

Comment: Thanks Gaston. It runs like a charm but I'm new to XML so I don't know how to implement it within Flash.

It´s possible to see the FLA? Thanks!

Comment: @Sergio, you're welcome. I created this example in flash builder 4.6, this is a flex project, with this ide i can compile and deploy the actionscript code into swf file. For create a fla project I suppose that you must use flash cs. If you want, i can upload the project that you see in the link that i sent you.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll try to adapt it to Flash CS5. Anyway, I'd like to review the example files. Cheers

Comment: @Sergio I edited the post, i uploaded the project file, please follow the instructions that I posted.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll download FBuilder and study your project. There are Flash Builder 4.7 and Flash Builder for PHP. What one I must download? It sounds obvious to me that the "PHP" version will do for both, XML and PHP projects. I'm right?

Comment: @Sergio, Sorry for the delay, i don't know the Flash ide for PHP, but i suppose that is similar to Flash builder with utilities/libraries for connect the flex app to PHP applications.

Answer (score -2):

Convert to an internal class, create a populate( data:XML ) and toXML():XML method. You will most likely have other methods in there.

Comment: Although the above answer satisfies our need, I believe mine comes from personal experience of working with Value Objects that come as XML. Thus I believe in the long run its more useful. Also, consider switching to JSON. AS3 has a native JSON parser.

Comment: I'll check JSON. Thank you.